# Magento custom admin menu dropdown

Tags: magento, module, admin

I need a little help: I’m developing an admin module, where I create two menus. I want to set the links in the config.xml, but I do not get it. My config.xml is as follows.

```xml
<children>
    <menuitem1 module="PrecosMargens">
        <title>Actualizar Preços Custos</title>
        <action>PrecosMargens/example</action>
    </menuitem1>
    <menuitem2 module="PrecosMargens">
        <title>Actualizar Preços vendas</title>
        <action>PrecosMargens/example2</action>
    </menuitem2>
</children>
```

But with the MenuItem2 get error 404. Can you help me how to solve this? In the controller file I have just as follows:

```php
class lbonus_PrecosMargens_ExampleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // "Fetch" display
        $this->loadLayout();

        // "Inject" into display
        // THe below example will not actualy show anything since the core/template is empty
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')

        //defino o template
        ->setTemplate('PrecosMargens/list.phtml')); 

        // "Output" display
        $this->renderLayout();

    }    
}
```

I wanted to do is to have two different layouts, one layout to another to link1 and link2

Answer (score 1):

The second action (`PrecosMargens/example2`) is trying to find a method `indexAction()` in a separate class `lbonus_PrecosMargens_Example2Controller`. You need two controllers for the two actions.

You could have one controller instead. Change the actions to `PrecosMargens/example/custos` and `PrecosMargens/example/vendas` which cause the matching methods `custosAction()` and `vendasAction()` to be used.

#### Addendum

The action (which becomes part of the URL) is in the form "router/controller/action". The router is matched to your module by the `<routers>` section of that module's config.xml file.
The controller becomes the class name with "Controller" appended to it, so in this case the "example" becomes your module's "ExampleController".
The action part leads to that class' method with "Action" appended to it. You can see "custos" becomes the `custosAction()` method.
When one of these parts is missing it defaults to "index", so a default controller is "IndexController" and a default action is "indexAction". If you just used "PrecosMargens" it would be used as if it were "PrecosMargens/index/index".

Comment: i try and it works, where is locate the "example" that comes from the action?
from where?
lbonus_PrecosMargens_ExampleController

Comment: Thanks friend clockworkgeek, you can tell me how add new field in catalog_category in administration?
thanks.

Comment: That sounds like it needs to be it's own question.

Comment: i make the costume atributte and i need set this in all products in table, i have more off 5000 products in db.
Please help me.
Thanks